# cmake project build only one specific executable (and its dependencies)

Tags: build, cmake, build-target

I have a CMake Project with roughly this structure:

```
.
|-- library1
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- library2
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- executables
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
```

I generate two executables in the folder named `executables`. I wonder if it was possible just generating one executable and its dependencies instead of all. I heard something about the cmake `--target` option but I cant get it to work with `cmake/3.13.4`.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to only *build* (i.e. compile) one executable? Or do you want to only *configure/generate* (at CMake-time) one executable?

Comment: @kamil i read it here on stackoverflow but i lost the link. I tried `cmake --build .. --target target_name` but I got the error message `CMake Error: The source directory "/build/target_name" does not exist.`

Comment: @squareskittles I want to compile the executable but only the one i name and its dependent libraries.

Comment: Your command line looks correct syntactically, but is your build folder actually named `build`? And did CMake generate for the target with name `target_name`?

Comment: How did you configure cmake ? The `--build` should point to the folder where you configured cmake.

Comment: @squareskittles yes the build folder is called `build`. Yes cmake was generating for my whole project. What I was thinking is that `target` might only refer to the project name and not a specific target created with `add_executable`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple potential issues here. First, the typical CMake workflow places the `build` folder as a sibling to the top-level CMake file. So your file hierarchy should look something like this:

```
.
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- library1
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- library2
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- executables
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- build    <------------ Run CMake commands from here.
```

This isolates all the CMake-generated files to the `build` folder. Secondly, you must to careful to run the CMake build stages in the proper location. We can run everything from within the `build` folder, for example:

1. To *generate the build system*, run `cmake ..` from the `build` directory. This first step should point to the top-level CMake file.
2. To *build* (or compile) a specific target, say it's called `MyExecutable1`, run this:

   ```
   cmake --build . --target MyExecutable1
   ```

   from the `build` directory. You must be sure to point the `--build` flag at the `build` folder, **not** the top-level CMake file this time. Also, the target name to specify in this command should match the target name used in `add_executable()`, **not** the project name or anything else.
3. As always, when getting errors/issues while attempting to run CMake, it helps to clear the cache (delete `build/CMakeCache.txt`), or just delete the `build` folder altogether and start fresh.

Comment: `cmake --build . --target MyExecutable1` seems not work. All targets still be configured.