# Custom command does not get executed with --target option in cmake

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

Followup question to this question: [cmake project build only one specific executable (and its dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412591/cmake-project-build-only-one-specific-executable-and-its-dependencies/57430481#57430481)

I have a custom target written so it will run every time i compile something in my project. Now that I call an explicit target as asked in the question above, this custom command does not get executed anymore.
Code:

```
add_custom_target(
    custom_command
    ALL
    DEPENDS hash.h
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "[INFO] CMake generating special *.h file from custom command magic."
)
```

I already tried removing the `ALL` directive but it did not change anything.

Forgot to add: I am using `cmake/3.13.4` compiled from source.

Comment: So, you run `cmake --build --target custom_command`?

Comment: And the dependency is fulfilled? And what COMMAND needs to be executed?

Comment: @arrowd no I am running `cmake --build . --target my_target` but inside `my_target` this command needs to be executed because I have to generate a `*.h` file that gets included by one of the project source files

Comment: Did not get it. I expected something like `add_custom_target(
    Generate_hash_h
    ALL
 COMMAND myhashgenerator.script hash.h
    DEPENDS hash.h
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "[INFO] CMake generating special *.h file from custom command magic."
)` within your code.

Comment: Yes, if you post more of your code, it may be easier to understand. Where is the script that generates the header? I don't see it in your `add_custom_target` command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the later answer but work was crazy. So after i read the comments by @Th.Thielemann and @squareskittles I reread the cmake documentation and found my solution. The following code was written under `cmake/3.0.0` quite a while ago:

```
add_custom_command( 
    OUTPUT some_header.h
    COMMAND cat ${BISON_HEADER} other_header.h | awk -f some_wak_file.awk > some_header.h
    DEPENDS ${BISON_HEADER}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(
    custom_command
    ALL
    DEPENDS some_header.h
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "[INFO] CMake generating special *.h file from custom command magic."
)
```

After reading up again on the documentation for `cmake/3.13` it became quite obvious that it could be written in an easier form:

```
add_custom_target(
    timex_utilities_hash 
    ALL
    COMMAND cat ${BISON_HEADER} other_header.h | awk -f some_wak_file.awk > some_header.h
    DEPENDS ${BISON_HEADER}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

Thank you again @Th. Thielemann and @squareskittles for the patients and the inut to check again!