# how to compile many specific targets in cmake/make

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am using CMake to generate Makefile.

Suppose I have the target `MyTarget1,MyTarget2,...,MyTarget100`

Now I only want obtain some specific targets, they are `MyTarget1, MyTarget2, MyTarget3, MyTarget4`.

I do not know how to do that.

I want something like

```
make MyTarget1,MyTarget2,MyTarget3,MyTarget4
```

or something like

```
cmake --build . --target MyTarget1,MyTarget2,MyTarget3,MyTarget4
```

I know that call the make or cmake many times must work. But I do not like the idea, because compile each target one by one leads to a lower parallism.

Thanks for your time.

#### Reference

Follow topic disscuss only obtain one target. I want many specific target.

[cmake project build only one specific executable (and its dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412591/cmake-project-build-only-one-specific-executable-and-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is very close; just use spaces to separate the target names instead of commas:

```
cmake --build . --target MyTarget1 MyTarget2 MyTarget3 MyTarget4
```

Please see the `cmake` command line [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project).

Comment: Thanks you sir, follow your link, then command should will work over cmake 3.15.